# Java serialization using objectMapper: serialize using private getter

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have a private field with a private getter method (because I hope to prevent other users from using the getter outside this class, while I have a use case for this getter within this class), but I hope the field to be serialized using objectMapper. What is a good way to do it? Would appreciate any idea!

```
@Data
public class TestClass{
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private String field
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ObjectMapper by default will serialize only public fields, but you can change it using `setVisibility` [method](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1597).
You can do it like this:

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass("field");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testClass);
```